# Is it possible to achieve chip in android where there are multiple texts and icons in between?

Tags: android, xml, android-chips

[image: chip]

This is what I want to achieve.
Is it possible to do that with Chip?

Comment: Do you want to display as a grid ??

Comment: why not just use a recyclerview

Comment: @Piyush No. only a single horizontal line.

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes. it's possible with recyclerview. But I was just wondering if simple chip can do that.

Comment: Then just go with Recylerview with horizontal layout manager